# Handling input from an input field or form field with Django

Tags: python, django, user-input, backend

So I'm trying to learn Django by building a very simple single-page site that just takes emails for subscriptions and stores it into djangos backend. I made an html page for the site that has form and input elements, and I've successfully rendered the page by following the documentation. I even built a model called 'subscriptions', to take email strings, but now i'm unsure about how to handle the input from the html page and store the emails in the backend.

All the documentation is kind of confusing cause it instructs me to build a separate .html file for the form, and handle it in another views and model page, which just seems unnecessary.

Does django necessitate handling input in a separate forms.html file? Or can i just use the index.html, and add views to 'views.py' or revise 'models.py'?

I'm pretty confused, all help and examples are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django documentation on [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) mentions a lot of examples around what you want to do.

Create  a forms.py as mentioned on the page and you can [create an equivalent view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) for it in `views.py` which recieves form values.

Once you have your form data in the view as shown in example, you can save it to using, as something like:

```
s = Subscriptions(email=email)
p.save()
```

Refer more on models [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/).

Comment: Thank you. I came across this while visiting those links and I think its a little more in line with my goal. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

What I should have clarified is that, creating a separate form seems redundant when I already have a model to store the data, low and behold modelforms. After that I needed help handling the post request when a user enters inputs email, but for that I just write a separate view. It's a little confusing to think about how views, requests, models, and templates are all organized but i think i got it now. thanks

Comment: Just start doing it and once you do enough research around the topic you will notice a lot of solutions for it. Do accept and upvote if answer is good enough for you